# winerror 10061 with python sockets on VPS

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, vps, ovh

I know there are already a lot of topics on this problem, but I still couldn't find any good answer to it so here I am.

I'm using Python3 to communicate between a host and a server. Everything worked just fine between two local machines, and I decided to put the server side on a VPS. Since then, i get this error everytime I try to connect to it :

`ConnectionRefusedError: [Winerror 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it`

I disabled the vps firewall, changed the port, the connexion target and everything. I tried to nmap the port and i get this result :

[image]

Here is my client code :

```
import socket


HEADER = 64
PORT = 40000
FORMAT = 'utf-8'
DECONNEXION = "!DECONNEXION"
SERVER = "vps-xxxxxxxx.vps.ovh.net"
ADDR = (SERVER, PORT)

client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client.connect(ADDR)

def envoyer(msg):
    message = msg.encode(FORMAT)
    message_longueur = str(len(message)).encode(FORMAT)
    message_longueur += b' '*(HEADER-len(message_longueur))

    client.send(message_longueur)
    client.send(message)
    print(client.recv(2048).decode(FORMAT))

def communication():
    while (True):
        envoyer(input())

communication()
```

Server :

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import socket 
import threading 

HEADER = 64
PORT = 40000
SERVEUR = socket.getfqdn(socket.gethostname())
ADDR = (SERVEUR, PORT)
FORMAT = 'utf-8'
DECONNEXION = "!DECONNEXION"

server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.bind(ADDR)

def handle_client(conn, addr):
    print("[NOUVELLE CONNEXION] :", addr)
    message=""
    connecte = True
    while connecte:
        longueur_message = conn.recv(HEADER).decode(FORMAT)
        if(longueur_message):
            longueur_message = int (longueur_message)
            message = conn.recv(longueur_message).decode(FORMAT)
            print("[", addr, "] : ", message)
            conn.send("Message reçu !".encode(FORMAT))

        if "!DECONNEXION" in message:
            connecte = False
    
    conn.close()

def start():
    server.listen()
    print("[STATUT] Serveur démarré sur", SERVEUR,":", PORT )
    while True:
        conn, addr = server.accept()
        thread = threading.Thread(target=handle_client, args=(conn, addr))
        thread.start()
        print("[CONNEXIONS] ", threading.active_count() -1 )
        

print("[STATUT] Le serveur démarre... ")
start()
```

But as I said, this code worked locally. Can it be that OVH has a funky firewall of his own that blocks tcp port 40000?
Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean with "disabled the VPS firewall"? Do you mean something like `ufw disable`? Have you looked through the OVH console? All cloud providers I've used have had some sort of default inbound traffic blocks. https://docs.ovh.com/ie/en/dedicated/firewall-network/

Comment: As an aside, your implementation of your communications protocol (although it has a length header -- well done!) isn't quite correct, since a message might be longer than a single `.recv()` call will receive.

Comment: (Also, you'll want to use `.sendall()` on the sending side...)

Comment: `ufw disable` is what i did and didn't change anything. I had already looked at this doc page but as it's told there, no firewall is enabled by default...

Comment: Well, then the obvious other idea is to try any other port, just in case your 40000 is unlucky :)

Comment: Oh, by the way: you'll want to change `ADDR` to `('0', PORT)` in the server to ensure you're binding to all hosts. I bet that's it :)

Comment: WAW ok that worked. I really don't understand why, but changing the hostname to '0' did the trick. Explainations senpai ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With

```
SERVEUR = socket.getfqdn(socket.gethostname())
ADDR = (SERVEUR, PORT)
server.bind(ADDR)
```

you're telling Python to bind the listening socket to only the interface with the `SERVEUR` local address, which might not be correct at all.

Instead, as mentioned in the comments, common options are

- `'0'` (short for `'0.0.0.0'`) to bind to all network interfaces (which is useful to expose a service to the Internet)
- `'127.0.0.1'` to bind to only the loopback network interface (which is useful in many proxying situations)

Of course, there are cases where you want to bind to a certain interface only, but the two above are the common cases.